# Translate non-uniqified json output into a summary table using jq

Tags: json, pivot-table, jq, export-to-csv

I am trying to transform job data from the `LSF` job scheduler into a summary table of hosts and statuses. For example this might be some sample data:

```
$ bjobs -q normal -a -uall -o 'exec_host stat' -json
{
  "COMMAND":"bjobs",
  "JOBS":5,
  "RECORDS":[
    {
      "EXEC_HOST":"compute-node-1",
      "STAT":"RUN"
    },
    {
      "EXEC_HOST":"compute-node-1",
      "STAT":"DONE"
    },
    {
      "EXEC_HOST":"compute-node-2",
      "STAT":"RUN"
    },
    {
      "EXEC_HOST":"compute-node-1",
      "STAT":"EXIT"
    },
    {
      "EXEC_HOST":"compute-node-2",
      "STAT":"RUN"
    },
```

And I want output that looks like:

```
                 RUN   DONE   EXIT
compute-node-1   1     1      1
compute-node-2   2
```

I can accomplish this through some really awkward contortions using `datamash`, but minimizing the workflow to `bjobs` and `jq` would significantly improve maintainability. I'm struggling to come up with the recipe to summarize the unique `EXEC_HOST`/`STAT` values.

Is there a way within `jq` to summarize this data as above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your input, the following invocation produces TSV output, as shown:

```
jq -r '
  .RECORDS 
  | (map(.STAT) | unique) as $statuses
  | reduce .[] as $x (null; .[$x.EXEC_HOST][$x.STAT] += 1)
  | [null, $statuses[]],
     (to_entries[] | [.key, .value[$statuses[]]])
  | @tsv
```

```
    DONE    EXIT    RUN
compute-node-1  1   1   1
compute-node-2          2
```

You can easily tweak the above, e.g. if you want more control over the ordering of the columns.  Also, you might want to use `@csv` instead of `@tsv`, etc....

Comment: Thank you! THe column ordering isn't critical, this gets me 90% of where I need to be. I appreciate it :)